# AWS unable to get query result because of ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get cloudwatch query with boto3, but I'm getting `ResourceNotFoundException`.

```py
import boto3
if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = boto3.client('logs')
    response = client.start_query(
        logGroupName='/aws/lambda/My-Stack-Name-SE349DJ',
        startTime=123,
        endTime=123,
        queryString="fields @message",
        limit=1
    )
```

I attempted to the above code. And an error message is as follows.

`botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the StartQuery operation: Log group '/aws/lambda/My-Stack-Name-SE349DJ' does not exist for account ID '11111111' (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: xxxxx-xxxx-xxx; Proxy: null)`

What I tested are as below.

1. The log group exists. I tested it with Logs Insights on the aws console. Also I tested after paste the log group as it is.
2. I added a backslash to test if '/' is a problem (ex. '/aws/lambda/My-Stack-Name-SE349DJ') and `InvalidParameterException` appears.
3. The aws account has administrate access privileges in the log group.
4. I got the same error message when I tested with aws cli.

`An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the StartQuery operation: Log group 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' does not exist for account ID '11111111' (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: xxxxx-xxxx-xxx; Proxy: null)`

How can I solve this problem?

Actually the reason why I'm trying this is because I need to get more than 500,000 data from the filtered log group, but 10,000 are the maximum. I think It's better to pull it out by changing the start time and end time.
There is a high possibility that there are too many data in certain time, so I think it would be better to run it with boto3 rather than directly. Is there an easy way to extract more than 500,000 pieces of data from the console or other methods?

Comment: Maybe the regions are different?

Comment: @Marcin Thank you, you're right. I added this lines before create client. 
`my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'us-east-2',
)
client = boto3.client('logs', config=my_config)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marcin commented, It was because of the region configuration.

I added these lines before creating an aws client.

```py
from botocore.config import Config 
...
my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'us-east-2',
)
...
client = boto3.client('logs', config=my_config)
```